# Hibernate Inheritance - Structure referring to Superclass

Tags: mysql, hibernate, inheritance, superclass

I want to create a structure to manage products in MYSQL using Hibernate 4.1. In general there are two kind of products: SimpleProduct (contains just description and price) and ComplexProduct (contains an extra list containing products again).

So I created an abstact class Product and the derived classes SimpleProduct and ComplexProduct. I thought the TABLE_PER_CLASS InheritanceType would be convenient.

**Product.java**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Product {

    private long id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;

    private Product parent;


    protected Product() {

    }

    protected Product(String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="PRICE", precision=2, columnDefinition="DECIMAL(10,2)")
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getDescription()+", "+getPrice()+"€";
    }

}
```

**SimpleProduct.java**

```java
@Entity
public class SimpleProduct extends Product {

    public SimpleProduct() {
        super();
    }

    public SimpleProduct(String description, BigDecimal price) {
        super(description,price);
    }

}
```

**ComplexProduct.java**

```java
@Entity
public class ComplexProduct extends Product  {

    private List<Product> containedProducts;

    public ComplexProduct() {

    }

    public ComplexProduct(String description, BigDecimal price, List<Product> containedProducts) {
        super(description,price);
        if (containedProducts == null) {
            this.containedProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
        } else {
            this.containedProducts = containedProducts;
        }
    }

    public ComplexProduct(String description, BigDecimal price) {
        super(description,price);
        this.containedProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Product.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Product> getContainedProducts() {
        return containedProducts;
    }

    public void setContainedProducts(List<Product> containedProducts) {
        this.containedProducts = containedProducts;
    }

    public void addToProductList(Product p) {
        this.containedProducts.add(p);
    }

}
```

Then i tried to execute a Teststructure:

```java
SimpleProduct sp1 = new SimpleProduct("SimpleProduct1",new BigDecimal("2.99"));
SimpleProduct sp2 = new SimpleProduct("SimpleProduct2",new BigDecimal("4.99"));
SimpleProduct sp3 = new SimpleProduct("SimpleProduct3",new BigDecimal("3.99"));

ComplexProduct cp1 = new ComplexProduct("ComplexProduct1",new BigDecimal("8.99"));
cp1.addToProductList(sp2);
cp1.addToProductList(sp3);

HibernateUtil.persist(sp1);
HibernateUtil.persist(sp2);
HibernateUtil.persist(sp3);

HibernateUtil.persist(cp1);

HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

And here is the persist method:

```java
public static void persist(Object o) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.persist(o);
    tx.commit();                        
}
```

I know, the persist-method for this teststructure is no very clean, but it is just to test.

The problem is that I get an Exception when the programm is executing **HibernateUtil.persist(cp1)**:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Product

So, what is wrong with it? And how can i solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution: if i use session.save(o) instead of session.persist(o) it works!